# why is my merge sort program giving an error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to code a merge sort program in Python:

```
def merge (list1 , list2) : 
    result = []
    while (len(list1) != 0 or len(list2) != 0) : 
        if (len(list1) == 1 and len(list2) == 0) :
            result.append(list1[0])
            del list1[0]
        elif (len(list1) == 0 and len(list2) == 1) :
            result.append(list2[0])
            del list2[0]
        else :
            if (list1[0]<list2[0]) : 
                result.append(list1[0])
                del list1[0]
            elif (list1[0]>list2[0]) : 
                result.append(list2[0])
                del list2[0]

    return result
```

but when I execute this code

```
print merge([43, 60], [71, 84])
```

I get the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mergesort.py", line 99, in <module>
    print merge([43, 60], [71, 84])
  File "mergesort.py", line 11, in merge
    if (list1[0]<list2[0]) :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why do i get this?

Comment: like it said because the list index is out of range. also, your code is running you meant to ask why you are getting an error.

Comment: A good technique for debugging would be to add numerous logs around your method that give you the state, where you suspect the problem could be. Such as the just before the lines mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You've iterated until you have `list1` empty, having moved both elements to `result`.  Using a simple trace at the problem point

```
    else :
        print "TRACE", list1, list2, result
        if (list1[0]<list2[0]) : 
            result.append(list1[0])
            del list1[0]
```

we see the iterative output

```
TRACE [43, 60] [71, 84] []
TRACE [60] [71, 84] [43]
TRACE [] [71, 84] [43, 60]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 21, in <module>
    print merge([43, 60], [71, 84])
  File "so.py", line 12, in merge
    if (list1[0]<list2[0]) : 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now that you know the root cause, I trust you can repair your code from here.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with `list1`. you keep deleting items from list1 on line 13 `del list1[0]` and when `list1` is empty then you try to access it with `list1[0]` on line 11 (`if (list1[0]<list2[0]) :`). there is nothing in the list so Python throws you an error of

> indexError: list index out of range